# How to make cpplint work with Jenkins warnings plugin

Tags: jenkins, compiler-warnings, lint, cpplint

I added an **'Execute shell'** build step in Jenkins to run the cpplint.py

```
python /var/lib/jenkins/scripts/cpplint.py --counting=detailed `find path -name *.cpp
```

I also added **'Scan for compiler warnings**' and added CppLint.

However it always gets 0 warnings even though it displayed in the Console output some warnings such as

```
filename.cpp:18:  Missing space after ,  [whitespace/comma] [3]
```

Comment: Manage to fix the problem by creating a custom parser using the code from [here](https://raw.github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-plugin/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/warnings/parser/CppLintParser.java)

Answer (score 6):

If you run cpplint.py with --output=vs7 it will produce the format expected by the Jenkins warnings plugin.

Answer (score 3):

I use the [Cppcheck Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cppcheck+Plugin) and [cpplint_to_cppcheckxml.py](https://gist.github.com/esutton/c19606e6962bfe535b1d80d672afb82b) to convert [cpplint.py](https://github.com/cpplint/cpplint) output to the XML format expected by [Cppcheck Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cppcheck+Plugin).  This works really well.  I can click on the offending issue in Cppcheck Results displayed on the Jenkins job page and it will display the source code with offending line highlighted.  Very cool.

You must provide [cpplint](https://github.com/cpplint/cpplint) an absolute path to your source code directory in order for the hyperlink generation to work on Cppcheck Results page.  The only con I see is your [Cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net) and cpplint results are combined and not separated.

If using Linux bash scripts, here is how I turn a relative path into absolute in order for the cpplint to generate absolute paths in it's output:

```
# Build cpplint reports and transform to cppcheck compatible XML format
# Convert relative path to absolute path so that Jenkins job can easily display the source code errors
srcPathAbsolute=${PWD}/../dicegame/src/main
srcPathAbsolute=$(readlink -f ${srcPathAbsolute})
cpplint.py --counting=detailed ${srcPathAbsolute}/*.cpp  2>&1| cpplint_to_cppcheckxml.py &> cpplint-cppcheck-result.xml
```

In my Jenkins job configuration to locate both ccplint-cppcheck-result.xml files and my normal cppcheck-result.xml.

```
Publish cppcheck results
Cppcheck report XMLs  **/*cppcheck-result.xml
```

Thanks to original developer of **cpplint_to_cppcheckxml.py**.  This script serves as an example on how to connect output of other tools into existing Jenkins plugins.  Very nice!

Comment: Reviving the question: could you provide both cpplint with example pattern.xml as well as recordIssues commands?